# How to use Selenium to get the parking price?

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use web scraping to get the parking price at this link, https://application.parkbytext.com/accountus/prepay.htm?locationCode=1127. It's **$2** for the day which is what I'm trying to get. I'm using python+selenium, but just couldn't get the parking price. Below is the code I'm using, but sometimes I hit the target but most time I get the error

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"gwt-RadioButton"}.`

Can anyone help? thanks in advance

```
def downtownparking(driver):
driver.get("https://application.parkbytext.com/accountus/prepay.htm?locationCode=1127")
try:
    ### driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 16)
    ### driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    cr = driver.find_element_by_class_name("gwt-RadioButton")
    dayprice = cr.find_element_by_tag_name("label")
    print (dayprice.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page loading takes time. At the moment webdriver tries to find an element, it is not yet present in the DOM tree. Add an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

cr = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "gwt-RadioButton"))
)
```

---

As a side, note, I would use the `input`'s name instead:

```
cr = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='periodType']/following-sibling::label"))
)
print(cr.text)  # prints "Day - $2.00"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help. It works. Actually I was wondering the wait was the reason. So I tried driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 16) or driver.implicitly_wait(20), but didn't work. Do you know why the explicit or implicit wait doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Sure I'll accept the answer. I just need to wait at least 10 minutes to click the button. You are awesome! Thanks for the overview link, I'll take a look.

Comment: oops, the revision didn't work. The first answer works though.